# How can Bash execute a command in a different directory context?

Tags: bash, shell, working-directory

I have a common command that gets called from within very specific directories. There is only one executable sitting in /bin for this program, and the current working directory is very important for running it correctly. The script affects the files that live inside the directory it is run within.

Now, I also have a custom shell script that does some things in one directory, but I need to call that command mentioned above as if it was in another directory.

How do you do this in a shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a program with a different working directory from current, from Linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `cd` builtin, or the `pushd` and `popd` builtins for this purpose. For example:

```
# do something with /etc as the working directory
cd /etc
:

# do something with /tmp as the working directory
cd /tmp
:
```

You use the builtins just like any other command, and can change directory context as many times as you like in a script.

Comment: There's also `cd -` in a POSIX shell to change back to the previous directory.  That said, (a) `pushd` and `popd` are really intended for interactive use, and (b) it's not always safe to assume that you can `cd` back where you started, *especially* in complex subsystems which may use restrictive permissions internally (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555284/in-what-way-is-fast-abs-path-dangerous-but-potentially-faster).

Comment: Using a subshell is a much better solution

Comment: For scripting, a subshell is probably a better idea.. However I'm really happy to learn about `popd`.

Comment: Can you please explain what does `:` symbol mean here?

Comment: @VadimKotov I think it's effectively a no-op. Relevant section of `man bash` reads:

`: [arguments]` No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections.  The return status is zero.

Comment: For anyone interested, look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin

Answer (score 346):

Use `cd` in a subshell; the shorthand way to use this kind of subshell is parentheses.

```
(cd wherever; mycommand ...)
```

That said, if your command has an environment that it requires, it should really ensure that environment itself instead of putting the onus on anything that might want to use it (unless it's an internal command used in very specific circumstances in the context of a well defined larger system, such that any caller already needs to ensure the environment it requires).  Usually this would be some kind of shell script wrapper.

Comment: You can also insert a ``\`` after each `;` for multi-line commands within the same context.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: This solution is good as long as spawning a new shell is not a problem.

Answer (score 53):

```
(cd /path/to/your/special/place;/bin/your-special-command ARGS)
```

Answer (score 30):

### If you want to return to your current working directory:

```
current_dir=$PWD;cd /path/to/your/command/dir;special command ARGS;cd $current_dir;
```

1. We are setting a variable `current_dir` equal to your `pwd`
2. after that we are going to `cd` to where you need to run your command
3. then we are running the command
4. then we are going to `cd` back to our variable `current_dir`

Or

```
pushd && cd /path/to/your/command/dir && special command ARGS && popd
```

Courtesy of @apieceofbart and @Konstantin

Comment: or you could do `pushd && YOUR COMMAND && pulld`

Comment: @apieceofbart I think you meant `popd` instead of `pulld`.

Comment: I beleive the last command should be
`pushd /path/to/your/command/dir && special command ARGS && popd`

Comment: These solutions can have weird outcomes in case your special command fails. The one with ";" won't propagate command return value but will keep che current working directory. The one with "&&" will leave you in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use the `env` command to achieve the same without an extra shell:

```
env --chdir=/whatever/path -S whatever_command -some -option and any other arguments
```

Where `whatever_command` is the command or script to be executed with all the relevant options and argument. All this must follow the `-S` option of the `env` command.

The current working directory is only changed for the `execvp()` system call so, at the end it will be back to its original value.

`env` is part of the [GNU `coreutils` package](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and a copy of its manual page can be found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) for more details.

For example you can use `env` also to manipulate the environment variables and the signal handling only for a specific execution.

This won't work with shell aliases and shell functions as `env` works only with programs.

Answer (score 2):

## W A R N I N G ! ! !

Comming late to this question, I have to see: **no answer here address [ShellCheck SC2164](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2164)!!**

> Use `cd ... || exit` in case `cd` fails,

Explanation:
If you hit some mispelled path before doing some destructive command:

```
( cd /wrong/path ; rm -fR * )
```

then the `cd` command will fail, but
     subsequent command will anyway *destroy everything in the **current directory!!***

So the correct command is

```
( cd /path/to/wherever || exit; mycommand ... )
```

(you could replace `exit` by `return` if in a *function* or `continue` if in a *loop*),

or

```
( cd /path/to/wherever && mycommand ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tibit helpful info:

This will change the shell directory to `~/project`

```bash
function mymake() {
    cd ~/project && make $1
}
```

This won't

```bash
function mymake() {
    (cd ~/project && make $1)
}
```

to run

```
mymake something
```

Comment: So essentially use curly braces and not parenthesis to wrap function contents.

Comment: No.  This is basically bad bash programming.  They are defining a function without a block, using a single set of parenthesis as the expression.  Parenthesis create a new shell which will exit, restoring the old shell.  If this person wanted to keep future bash programmers from frustration in debugging sessions, they would have done `function mymake() { ( cd ~/project && make $1 ) }` to avoid the easy mistake that the parenthesis are curly braces.