# Running `ng build` in a specific directory

Tags: bash, angular-cli

I'm writing an automated build script that needs to run `ng build` in a specific directory.  My project has the following structure:

```
project
├ build-script
└ project-client
  └ package.json
```

`ng build` is looking for the package.json file, but it can't find it in its current location.  Is there a way I can direct `ng build` to the subdirectory without doing a `cd` (since bash is a bit wonky about changing directories)?  Essentially, I just need a way to tell `ng build` to operate in a directory that I specify.

I have tried doing `ng build ./project-client/` but it is giving the error that "You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command"

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Bash execute a command in a different directory context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566532/how-can-bash-execute-a-command-in-a-different-directory-context)

Comment: @4castle Specifying the directory in that way did not work.  I'm hoping there's something similar to how `--prefix` works for `npm`

Comment: The documentation for [`ng build`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) makes no mention of such a flag, so I don't think it exists. Could you explain in more detail how it didn't work? A [mcve] would be appreciated.

Comment: @4castle As noted in the question, it's giving the error "You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command"

Comment: I meant the error that you get when you use `cd`.

Comment: `cd` within a bash script doesn't actually change the directory for the rest of the script, only the subshell that the command runs in.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script .  The workaround would be adding an alias to .bashrc, which I would like to avoid since the relative path to the project is subject to change.

Comment: Did you try creating a subshell like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566575/5743988) with `(cd project-client; ng build)`?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When I need to go to certain directory just to run a script I usually use `pushd` and `popd`. Example:

```
pushd /path/to/dir
ng build
popd
```

After this snippet is run your working directory (`pwd`) will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 12):

*Note: This answer is specific to Angular commands*

You can leverage the `npm run` command to run an Angular command while using the parameter `--prefix` to indicate the sub-directory.

---

#### Example 1: Original question (`ng build`)

Since Angular already has a shortcut for this command, you can simply run

```
npm run build --prefix path\to\Angular\project
```

---

#### Example 2: Custom command (Eg: `ng build --prod`)

First, create a shortcut for this command in your `package.json` file

```js
{
    "scripts": {
        // "CMD-SHORTCUT": "custom-command"
        "prod-build": "ng build --prod"
    },
}
```

Then, run the new shortcut in the same way as example 1:

```
npm run prod-build --prefix path\to\Angular\project
```

Comment: It seems that`--prefix` is not accessible now, not found in `ng build --help`

Comment: Unfortunately, the npm devs do not like anyone using `--prefix` which is why they have explicitly decided not to document it ([see this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1368))

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did.

```
pushd angular-src && ng build && popd
```